# Diagram draw with xy package looks wrong

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I'm trying out the xy package and have compiled one of the examples on this website: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Graphics#Xy-pic

```
\begin{displaymath}
    \xymatrix{
        A \ar[d] \ar[dr] \ar[r] & B \\
        D                       & C }
\end{displaymath}
```

But when I compile the latex code with `latex test.tex` and look at the resulting test.dvi, I get this:

[image: image as appears in test.dvi]

The arrow pointing to the bottom right looks wrong. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** Here's the full latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    A \ar[d] \ar[dr] \ar[r] & B \\
    D                       & C }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post your *entire* test document?  I get the right rendering when I include the snippet in a minimal document.

Comment: Turn the `.dvi` file into a `.ps` file using `dvips test` in a terminal, or compile with `pdflatex` directly.

Comment: I converted the dvi into pdf using dvipdf. It still looks a little bit wobbly when I view it with evince pdf viewer, but when I print it out it looks fine.

Comment: evince 2.32.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 certainly has problems with this. On my system it shows the nodes correctly but only the vertical and horizontal lines are shown. Even at high magnification there are no arrowheads or diagonal line. okular, spawg, spawx11, xgdvi and xdvi show the same .dvi correctly.

Answer (score 1):

By compiling with `pdflatex` you can use the package `xypdf`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xypdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    A \ar[d] \ar[dr] \ar[r] & B \\
    D                       & C }
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

One important comment by [Matsaya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3172/matsaya):

> after test, I want to say that `xypdf` is now an
>   integrated to `xy`. Indeed, when you try to compile the examples of the
>   `xypdf` manual with pdfLaTeX and the new `xy` package, it works just fine
>   (the same as with the old fashion way `xy + xypdf`).

Comment: compiling your code returns `LaTeX Error: File 'xy.sty' not found.` I tried finding the file 'xy.sty' on the net but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @LeonLampret: [`xy`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/) isn't the problem. [`xypdf`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/xypdf) was removed from the package repository. I don't know why.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: after test, I want to say that xypdf is now an integrated to xy. Indeed, when you try to compile the examples of the xypdf manual with pdfLaTeX and the new xy package, it works just fine (the same as with the old fashion way xy + xypdf).